# R Data Restructuring - Melt2

Tags: r, melt

```
 V1      V2      V3      V4
 Control Control Unknown Unknown
 0       2       0       2
 66      10      90      70
```

The rows mean:
Experiment,
Time,
Length, respectively

How would you restructure the above data to look so it looks like the below using melt2?

```
V1      V2 V3
Control 0  66
Control 2  10
Unknown 0  90
Unknown 2  70
```

Thanks for your time.

p.s: I am novice programmer trying to learn R

Comment: There was an error when reading the data — the first row should really be the column headers. You can change this by using the `header = TRUE` argument in the function call that reads the data. After that, melting is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base R (meaning no external library/package) and simply use [transpose](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html).

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c("Control", "0", "66"),  
                 V2=c("Control", "2", "10"),  
                 V3=c("Unknown", "0", "90"),
                 V4=c("Unknown", "2", "70"))    

reshape_df <- as.data.frame(t(df))
row.names(reshape_df) <- NULL

# CLEAN-UP
names(reshape_df)[1] <- "Experiment"
reshape_df$Experiment <- as.character(reshape_df$Experiment)
names(reshape_df)[2] <- "Time"
reshape_df$Time <- as.numeric(as.character(reshape_df$Time))
names(reshape_df)[3] <- "Length"
reshape_df$Length <- as.numeric(as.character(reshape_df$Length))
```

**Output**

```
Experiment  Time   Length
Control     0      66
Control     2      10
Unknown     0      90
Unknwon     2      70
```